# Use doc as computed property (Vue, nedb, Electron)

Tags: vue.js, electron, nedb

I've installed [nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) to my setup running Vue and Electron following [this guide](https://simulatedgreg.gitbooks.io/electron-vue/content/en/savingreading-local-files.html). I get no errors when setting up the database and everything seems to be working storage wise.

I'm having trouble displaying the contents of a doc though. I'm probably misunderstanding how to do it.

The way I've done it now is that I first off have this test method in Vue called `savePreset()`. It just creates a doc and insert it into the database with the following code from the readme of nedb:

```
savePreset(){
        var doc = { hello: 'world'
               , n: 5
               , today: new Date()
               , nedbIsAwesome: true
               , notthere: null
               , notToBeSaved: undefined  // Will not be saved
               , fruits: [ 'apple', 'orange', 'pear' ]
               , infos: { name: 'nedb' }
               };
          this.$db.insert(doc, function (err, newDoc) {   // Callback is optional
            // newDoc is the newly inserted document, including its _id
            // newDoc has no key called notToBeSaved since its value was undefined
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              console.log(newDoc)
            }
          });
      }
```

The `newDoc` is logged to the console when calling this method, so the insertion is working. I then try to output the contents of the doc in order to eventually loop through it and create one element for each item in the doc. I try to do this with a computed property, like this:

```
getDB(){
        return this.$db.find({ hello: 'world' }, function (err, docs) {
          // docs is an array containing documents Mars, Earth, Jupiter
          // If no document is found, docs is equal to []
          return docs
        });
      }
```

However, `getDB` is `undefined` when doing this. When I try `console.log(docs)` in the same function, it logs an array with the objects that I've added with the `savePreset` method. So it seems to be able to fetch the doc by logging it in the function, but nothing is displaying on the front end when I try to output the property with `{{getDB}}`.

I suspect that I have to do it another way. Any ideas?

Comment: The `this.$db.find` function is asynchronous and therefore returns nothing.

Comment: Ah, didn't think of that. What are the recommended procedures to get an async value as a computed property?

Comment: You can try promisification for this function (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html). And then use `await`...

Answer (score 0):

No need for promises or `async`/`await`. You could simply set a local data property in your `$db.insert` callback (convert that to an arrow-function beforehand to preserve context):

```
// script
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      doc: null, 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    savePreset() {
      ...
      this.$db.insert(doc, (err, newDoc) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          console.log(newDoc)

          this.doc = newDoc 
        }
      })
    }
  }
}

//template
<ul>
  <li v-for="(val, key) in doc" v-if="val">{{key}}: {{val}}</li>
</ul>
```

[image: Edit Iterating an object with v-for]